# I'm having a program when I'm trying to run my server it's a pretty simple server because I'm quite new with Django

Tags: python, django

This is the error I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. 
Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

I tried removing the include() function, but I still get the error, what should I do?

Here is the code:

## This is the main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
```

## This is the secondary urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: I suggest you follow a tuturial to learn Django. I learned it by following the course `https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/04/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-1.html` but probably there are more up-to-date tutorials that are using Django 2.

Comment: I'm currently learning from a book called python crash course, and I'm stuck on trying to open the website because of this error.

Comment: If you are following the book, no doubt what is written will give you a running web app. Just take a break, clear your head do something else and if necessary start the exercise from scratch.

Comment: thank you for your help, I think I'll take a break for an hour or too because I've been trying for 3 hours now. I'll check out this book for sure.

Comment: good luck, if you are new to Python using Django and building a web app is quite challenging!

Comment: To get access to the source code of Python Crash Course ... follow the link: https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc

Comment: thank you I went through it and there were a lot of  changes to book for the newer version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not left empty the path. Try this:

```
url(r'^/', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
```

Anyway, if you are using a django v2 or higher. I recommend you to use `re_path` and `path` methods. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
The new methods are more explicit and less error prone.

Comment: I'm on a v2 Django, how can i implement the path method into my current code , (sorry if this question is so basic) but i don't have that much experience with Django. thank you for responding.

Comment: Read the documentation and experiment with it. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help i fixed the problem by removing the namespace method from my main urls.py file and changed url to path, Problem Solved!

Comment: the documentation is actually very useful in that regard